# C++ MySQL For A Gaming Server

Tags: c++, mysql, c

Which are the steps to set up MySQL to a gaming server using C++ code?

---

1. What is a multithread environment and which are the differences between libmysqlclient_r.a and libmysqlclient.a?
2. Which is the option needed for my program to reconnect in problem cases?

---

Another question is how to avoid problems when the remote host is down?

Comment: The code you have supplied is not sufficient for us to give you an answer on where you are making your mistake(s): maybe leaking memory, algorithms are all 2^n, hogging more resources than needed, poor implementation, ... -- could be a variety of issues. I am not per say an experienced user, but I do not feel as if this question "as-is" is appropriate for SO.

Comment: Updated. Please answer again.

Answer (score 2):

1. You must check if you are using `mysql-library` in a multi-thread envrionment, if so you should link to `libmysqlclient_r.a` but not `libmysqlclient.a`.
2. If you are in multithread environment, call `my_init` in main once, this will stop you from crashing basically.
3. Keep long connection with mysql, this means `mysql_init`, `mysql_connect` is called only once, and you should set some option to tell client library to do reconnect if necessary.
4. You may abstract your design, objects like "result set" which contains some "result row" is needed, and this can help you design an more general db visiting layer for future development.

Comment: What about Windows? libmysqlclient_r.a is for Linux.
What do you mean with a multi-threaded environment?
How to tell library to do reconnect if necessary?

Comment: you can set some options to tell mysql client to reconnect with server if lose, you may learn about the function 'mysql_options' to get know about these.